# Flexbox align-items not working on Link components inside unordered list

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox, next.js

I am trying to make a basic navigation bar using flexbox, but it seems that the content of the unordered list don't get centered vertically.
Here is the HTML code:

```css
*,*::before,*::after{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
header{
  background-color: black;
}
.header{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
nav ul li{
  list-style: none;
}
nav ul{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
a{
color:white;
}
```

```html
  <header>
            <div className="header">
                <Link href="/"><a className="links">Mody<span>Chat</span></a></Link>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <Link href="/about"><a className="links">About</a></Link>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <Link href="/contact"><a className="links">Contact</a></Link>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
                <Link href="/signup"><a className="links">Join Us!</a></Link>
            </div>
        </header>
```

and here how it looks:
[image]

Comment: Are you using bootstrap here?

Comment: I am importing the bootstrap module in the _app.js file

Comment: It is because of `margin`. Just remove the margin and it should work as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some `margin-bottom` on the `ul`

so you can remove the margin as

```
ul{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;    // change
}
```

Comment: It worked! thanks mate, but why didn't the margin and padding reset take effect on the ul?

Comment: Have you reseted `margin` and `padding` on `ul`?

Comment: I am not really that great in Css but I thought that styling the *, *::before and *::after affects all elements?

Comment: `::before` and `::after` is used for different purpose and if you remove margin and padding on these elements then it might work in a different way. I thought you might have reset `padding` and `margin` initially for `ul`. Seems that is not the case...

Comment: Fair enough, anyways thanks so much for the help.